# Явное создание rvalue ссылки

Tags: c++, rvalue

Почему в коде:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void Foo(const std::vector<int> &mas)
{
    std::cout << "&" << std::endl;
}

void Foo(std::vector<int> &&mas)
{
    std::cout << "&&" << std::endl;
}

std::vector<int> Bar()
{
    return {1,2,3,4,5};
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> &&mas = Bar();
    Foo(mas);
    return 0;
}
```

[Вызывается](http://cpp.sh/7d3st) первая перегрузка Foo, а не вторая, как, казалось бы, должно быть?

Comment: Потому что mas lvalue. Не путайте l/rvalue и l/rvalue-reference.

Comment: Но при явной передаче: `Foo(Bar());` вызывается вторая перегрузка. Не могу понять логики, rvalue-reference что ли нельзя создать явно?